# Extra columns coming when pulling data with EntityFramework

Tags: c#

When i pulled my data from database with EntityFramework, datagridview has extra columns like this:

[extra columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02auH.png)

[extra columns 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiPbF.png)

[My Logs Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfumg.png)

Here is my code:

```
var result = db.Logs.ToList();
dgvLogs.DataSource = result;
```

My context code:

```
    public class TOKMANContext : DbContext
{
    public TOKMANContext() : base("TOKMANConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Records> Records { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Status> Status { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Brands> Brands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogTypes> LogTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Logs> Logs { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TOKMANContext>(null);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Logs : TOKMANContext
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int typeid { get; set; }
        public int userid { get; set; }
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Do all your entities inherit from `TOKMANContext`? That is your problem.

Comment: C# naming conventions, in a nutshell: PublicThings, ClassesAndMethods, _privateFields, localThings. 3+ letter acronyms like a word: HttpClient, SmtpClient XmlReader

Comment: @DavidG that and `dgv.AutoGenerateColumns=true` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Logs` class is inheriting from `TOKMANContext`, which means it inherits all `DBSet`s you defined in `TOKMANContext`. That is why you have the extra columns.

If there is no other reason, you should probably remove the inheritance in Logs and leave the class as:

```
public class Logs
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int typeid { get; set; }
    public int userid { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Normally for a question like this, we would just close it rather than answer since it doesn't really help any future visitors.

Comment: @DavidG this rule makes sense. I was thinking if I should delete the answer or not, but considering how specific the question is, I don't think it might lead other astray, so I'm thinking of leaving it as is. I saw how much you contributed, so if you think otherwise, do tell :)

Comment: It's here now so feel free to leave it. :)